# valgrind reports uninitialised value in BSONObj::toString with a simple BSON object created with GENOID

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

Using valgrind on a very simple example from the C++ driver of mongodb, it appears that something is wrong as soon as we use GENOID explicitly in the definition of a BSONObj. Here is an example that illustrates the problem:

(tested on gcc 4.4.5, boost 1.42, debian 6, mongodb C++ driver 2.2)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include "mongo/db/jsobj.h"

main()
{
  mongo::BSONObj p = BSON( mongo::GENOID << "name" << "Joe" << "age" << 33 );
  std::string s = p.toString();
  std::cout << s;
}
```

When run with valgrind, we get this message:

```
==2506== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==2506==    at 0x40A66B: mongo::toHexLower(void const*, int) (hex.h:64)
==2506==    by 0x40A73F: mongo::OID::str() const (oid.h:66)
==2506==    by 0x40A798: mongo::operator<<(mongo::StringBuilderImpl<mongo::TrivialAllocator>&, mongo::OID const&) (oid.h:140)
==2506==    by 0x40DCC1: mongo::BSONElement::toString(mongo::StringBuilderImpl<mongo::TrivialAllocator>&, bool, bool, int) const (bson-inl.h:765)
==2506==    by 0x40C898: mongo::BSONObj::toString(mongo::StringBuilderImpl<mongo::TrivialAllocator>&, bool, bool, int) const (bson-inl.h:475)
==2506==    by 0x40C5A5: mongo::BSONObj::toString(bool, bool) const (bson-inl.h:445)
==2506==    by 0x40A1B8: main (mongobug.cc:10)
```

If I remove the GENOID from the BSONObj definition, the problem is gone. This is a minimalist version of a more complex but similar problem I have when I use mongo::OID::gen() in my project.

The example above is taken from the official mongodb C++ driver tutorial here: http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=133415#C%2B%2BTutorial-BSON

Any idea what could be wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: What happens if you run this code?  Problem or no?

Comment: Also what version of valgrind is this?

Comment: valgrind 3.6.0, debian 6 64bits

Answer (score 1):

After careful review with the mongodb team, it would seem that there is nothing wrong with the mongodb code. I suspected a struct alignment issue in a union that is used in oid.h, but it is properly aligned with a #pragma pack(1) directive.

I tend to think it would rather be a false positive of valgrind, due to the not so simple structure of a union of struct used in the definition of the mongo::OID class. If anyone can reproduce the problem and figure a definitive answer, I'd be interested. Thanks!